# grep a word from fixed length file .dat

Tags: shell, unix

dat file having fixed length data in it. and i need to find how many repeated words are there in one file,

EG:

```
FHEAD0000000001STKU201508190000002015081900000000003882S0003110120SSS  0
FDETL132000000033333333333030000002
FTAIL0001200089
FHEAD0000000001STKU201508190000002015081900000000003882S0003110120SSS  0
FDETL132000000033333333333030000002
FTAIL0001200089
```

in the above example 2 FHEAD is there so how can i find how many FHEAD is there in a file starting from position 1 usigng grep command in unix?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -c` to get the count of lines matched:

```
grep -c 'FHEAD' file
```

You need to understand that this will not be not counting multiple occurrences of `FHEAD` in same line.

To count multiple occurrences of `FHEAD` in same line as well use `grep -o`

```
grep -o 'FHEAD' file | wc -l
```